# Provisioning profile managed by XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I let XCode manage the provisioning profiles automatically by entering my account details into Preferences > Account. Now what should I do to allow a team member to compile the app into a device (whose UDID is already added), if I don't want to give him the account password?

The certificat and key are already exported to .p12.

I tried to find the provisioning profile (Preferences > Account > View Details > Provisioning Profiles > Show in Finder) and sent it to him, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's recommended approach for this is to have the developer create their own developer account (if they don't already), and then add them as a team member on your "team".  You can do this through the "People" tab in Member Center.  You probably only want to grant them the role of "Member", which would allow them to get the certificates and profiles, but not allow them to create their own provisioning profiles / IDs, Certificates.

For more information, see Apple's site: https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.php

For information on the roles, see this link: https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/